# no suitable method found for getText(String)

Tags: java

I am new to java "I get this error 
"no suitable method found for getText(String)
    method JTextComponent.getText(int,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method JTextComponent.getText() is not applicable

### (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

(Alt-Enter shows hints)" 
when ever I try to run my program. Please help. What am I doing wrong?

```
package Introduction;

import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class chaineCaractereNombre extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private Object valeurSaisieTfd;


    public chaineCaractereNombre() {
        this.cptr = 0;
        initComponents();
            valeur = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            int intervalle =auHasardEntre(valeur, valeur + 100);
            Border cadre = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" أختار رقما بين " + intervalle +
                                                                " و " + (intervalle +100 ) + "، عليك أن تخمن ما هو؟... " );
                TitrePnl.setBorder(cadre);
                TitrePnl.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        TitrePnl = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        saisieTfd = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        okBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        InfoPnl = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        resultatTfd = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        ScorePnl = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        scoreLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        TitrePnl.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "اخترت عددا، فما هو؟", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.RIGHT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION));

        saisieTfd.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.RIGHT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION));
        saisieTfd.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                saisieTfdKeyReleased(evt);
            }
        });

        okBtn.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        okBtn.setText("نعم");
        okBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                okBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout TitrePnlLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(TitrePnl);
        TitrePnl.setLayout(TitrePnlLayout);
        TitrePnlLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            TitrePnlLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(TitrePnlLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                .addComponent(saisieTfd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 256, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(okBtn)
                .addGap(42, 42, 42))
        );
        TitrePnlLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            TitrePnlLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, TitrePnlLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(TitrePnlLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(okBtn)
                    .addComponent(saisieTfd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(141, 141, 141))
        );

        InfoPnl.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "لمزيد من المعلومات", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.RIGHT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION));

        resultatTfd.setColumns(20);
        resultatTfd.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Simplified Arabic", 0, 9)); // NOI18N
        resultatTfd.setRows(5);
        resultatTfd.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.RIGHT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION), "", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.RIGHT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION), "", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.RIGHT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION), "", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.RIGHT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION));
        resultatTfd.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR));
        resultatTfd.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                resultatTfdPropertyChange(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout InfoPnlLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(InfoPnl);
        InfoPnl.setLayout(InfoPnlLayout);
        InfoPnlLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            InfoPnlLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(InfoPnlLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addComponent(resultatTfd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 267, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        InfoPnlLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            InfoPnlLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, InfoPnlLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(28, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(resultatTfd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 77, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(31, 31, 31))
        );

        ScorePnl.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "عداد", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.RIGHT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION));

        scoreLbl.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        scoreLbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 48)); // NOI18N
        scoreLbl.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(100, 100, 100));
        scoreLbl.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        scoreLbl.setText("10");
        scoreLbl.setOpaque(true);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout ScorePnlLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(ScorePnl);
        ScorePnl.setLayout(ScorePnlLayout);
        ScorePnlLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            ScorePnlLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 167, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(ScorePnlLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(ScorePnlLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(scoreLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 138, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(19, 19, 19)))
        );
        ScorePnlLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            ScorePnlLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 132, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(ScorePnlLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(ScorePnlLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(scoreLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 110, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap()))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 499, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(TitrePnl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(InfoPnl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(ScorePnl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGap(29, 29, 29))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(TitrePnl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(InfoPnl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(ScorePnl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        TitrePnl.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("لقد اخترت عددا، ما هو؟");

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private int auHasardEntre (int min, int max){
        int resultat = (int) ((max-min) *Math.random() + min);
        saisieTfd.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

        return resultat;
    }
    private void okBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        //saisir la valeur au clavier
    jouer();

    }                                     

    private void resultatTfdPropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void saisieTfdKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.out.println(evt.getKeyCode());
        if(evt.getKeyCode() == 10){
        jouer(); 
    }                                     

}
        private void jouer(){
       int valeurSaisie = Integer.parseInt(saisieTfd.getText());
       //1: Effacer le contenu de champ de saisie
        saisieTfd.getText("");
        filDariane = filDariane + valeurSaisie + ">";
        //2: Passer a la ligne au bout de 4 valeurs saisie
        cptr++;
        if(cptr > 4){
         filDariane += "\n";
         cptr = 0;
        }
        resultatTfd.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        score--;
        scoreLbl.setText(Integer.toString(score));
        if(valeur + 100 == valeurSaisie){
        // Cas : L'utilisateur gagne
        resultatTfd.setText(" أصبت!!! ");
        }else{
        // Cas : L'utilisateur a perdu
            if(valeurSaisie > valeur + 100){
            resultatTfd.setText("أكبر!! " + filDariane );
            }else{
            resultatTfd.setText("أصغر !!  " + filDariane );
            }  
        }  
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]){
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(chaineCaractereNombre.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(chaineCaractereNombre.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(chaineCaractereNombre.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(chaineCaractereNombre.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new chaineCaractereNombre().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private int valeur;
    private int score=10;
    private int cptr=0;
    private String filDariane="";
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel InfoPnl;
    private javax.swing.JPanel ScorePnl;
    private javax.swing.JPanel TitrePnl;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JButton okBtn;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea resultatTfd;
    private javax.swing.JTextField saisieTfd;
    private javax.swing.JLabel scoreLbl;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: This is very long.  Have you tried paring this down to just the offending region?  I'm only seeing a getText(""); and getText();

Comment: javac is a king. Just try to compile your code and you will see the problem.

Comment: @Chiron the compiler is raising that error code. And OP's using NetBeans, but since the question is not about netbeans, I removed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, in method `private void jouer()`:

```
saisieTfd.getText("");
```

You're sending an empty `String` as parameter when this method doesn't need any parameter at all. Just remove the empty string from there:

```
saisieTfd.getText();
```

Or probably you want to set the text to an empty string. If this is what you want/need, then call `setText`:

```
saisieTfd.setText("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call

```
saisieTfd.getText(""); // <-- get doesn't take a String
```

I think you wanted

```
saisieTfd.setText(""); // <-- like this
```